# How to parse geo coordinates in different formats

Tags: c#, parsing, textbox, coordinates

Does anyone know of a C# library that can parse geo coordinates from one string without having to specify the format upfront. The goal is to enable "google like" data entry and interpretation.

Some formats that should be supported:

- "12 34.56'N 123 45.55'E"
- "12°N 34°W"
- "12.345°N 123.456°E"
- ...

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505). What have you tried?

Comment: Tried writing my own parser.. but I feel this should already exist out there but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been working on a simple geospatial library which can parse coordinate strings. It is called [Geo](https://github.com/sibartlett/Geo), and is licensed under the LGPL.

The Coordinate class has a static Parse method, and a couple of static TryParse methods.